# What is a step-by-step procedure to follow to submit a sharelatex-generated paper to arXiv?

Tags: mac, external-files, sharelatex, arxiv

I don't have Tex installed on my MacBookAir laptop. I have a paper I've written that is on sharelatex.com. The paper has several pdf figures and a .bib file.

I'd like to know a general step-by-step procedure to follow by which to submit the paper to arXiv.